# Combine multiple Tabs with common tables in Google Sheets

Tags: join, google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula

Good day! I'm quite new with sheets so I hope that  am asking the right question. Please see the link for the sample file below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDBqzwsyakyP3RGWAdNKs76Ia7JOGFwjIl_czREU0s0/edit?usp=sharing

What I'm trying to do is that I'd like to combine 4 tabs of schedule into 1, with the first column being combined in the process (note that "NAME") column may have additional entries on week 2 and so on. Once I have that info in the "Combined" Tab, I will then combine it with 12 similar worksheets. I hope that I can get this one done first, I just learned about the importrange function, Hope you can also give me some tips on how to make it faster if I get to that second step in creating my consolidated file. Thanks in advance and more power to the people of Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({UNIQUE(QUERY({'Week 1'!A:A; 'Week 2'!A:A; 'Week 3'!A:A; 'Week 4'!A:A}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)),
 VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({'Week 1'!A:A; 'Week 2'!A:A; 'Week 3'!A:A; 'Week 4'!A:A}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)), 'Week 1'!A:H, COLUMN(B:G), 0), 
 VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({'Week 1'!A:A; 'Week 2'!A:A; 'Week 3'!A:A; 'Week 4'!A:A}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)), 'Week 2'!A:H, COLUMN(B:G), 0),
 VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({'Week 1'!A:A; 'Week 2'!A:A; 'Week 3'!A:A; 'Week 4'!A:A}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)), 'Week 3'!A:H, COLUMN(B:G), 0),
 VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY({'Week 1'!A:A; 'Week 2'!A:A; 'Week 3'!A:A; 'Week 4'!A:A},
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)), 'Week 4'!A:H, COLUMN(B:G), 0)}))
```

[image]

then use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1eDBqzwsyakyP3RGWAdNKs76Ia7JOGFwjIl_czREU0s0", "Combined!A1:100")
```

Comment: Hi @player0 ! Could you please provide some explanation on your answer and a link to the relevant formulas? Thanks !

Comment: @MateoRandwolf https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDBqzwsyakyP3RGWAdNKs76Ia7JOGFwjIl_czREU0s0/edit#gid=1480989280&range=A1

Comment: As the user has not provided any explanation on how this formula works or any reference to the functions used here is a little explanation. [ARRAY FORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) is used to return a range rather than a single value. In our case this range would be the combination of the data from the other sheets. [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) checks if this range is equivalent to ```N/A``` (not a possible value i.e an error) and returns 0 if that is the case (otherwise it returns the range).

Comment: Those two functions are applied to all the inner functions and therefore to our output range. The formula basically first looks on each sheet for the values corresponding to each row we are trying to merge in (this is One, Two, Three, etc) by using [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en). Then, to remove duplicates between the sheets it uses [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) and then it uses [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to select the correct information and display it accordingly.